# Using PHPMailer if form submits

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I'm trying to run PHPMailer only if my form is submitted. I've tried it a few different ways but no success.

I'm also not sure what part of this code actually sends the email. When I test it using

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

it works, so I know it runs correctly. Any ideas why this code doesn't work?

```
<?php

    require_once 'C:\wamp\www\phpmailer\PHPMailer-master\PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com   ';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'test@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('tester@gmail.com', 'Marco');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'NEW APPLICATION';
    $mail->Body    = "--PERSONAL INFORMATION--
First Name: $fname Middle Name: $mname Last Name: $lname
Address:$address City:$city State:$state Zip:$zip ";

    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
$mail->send();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Since you've tried checking debug info then I assume you're not seeing any failures there. It is possible that your recipient email is flagging the mail as spam and this could happen for many reasons: SPF not set for sender, sender host is blacklisted, etc. I would check your mailer logs to see what is wrong.

Comment: No, that's not possible because it sent using the test code I posted above just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the test for `isset($_POST['Submit'])` is failing it either means that the `Submit` param is not provided, *or* it's present with a null value. This is a hazard of using `isset` rather than a more accurate check like `array_key_exists('Submit', $_POST)`.

Also why check for the presence of that param so late? Check it earlier so you can skip all that other PHPMailer code that's not going to be used.